# Правильная обработка поля textarea

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Сколько ищу, нигде не могу найти внятной инфы о том, как обрабатывать данные, вводимые в textarea... что запрещать, что разрешать... че за bb-теги... что и как там разрешать... выручайте, пацаны-кодеры

Answer (score 1):

Данные в textarea - это обычный текст с переносами строки. Обрабатывать можно как и любой другой.

Есть функция nl2br(), переводит переносы строк в `<br />`

bbкоды [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BbCode)

Comment: а как bb-тегами можно испортить жизнь админу? и как этого избежать?

Comment: У них ведь есть стандарт, можно регулярками вырезать.

Comment: Какой старнарт? объясни, пожалуйста...

Comment: [b]полужирный текст[/b]
зная как выглядит тег, можно делать с ним что хочешь

Comment: а подробнее можно?

Answer (score 0):

Для борьбы с длинным словом - [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php), обратить внимание на коменты

Answer (score -1):

Если данные, поступающие в textarea, используются при работе с базой данных, необходимо позаботиться о защите от SQL-инъекций. В php обычно обрабатывают вход с помощью `mysql_real_escape_string`. Остальное имеет значение, если данные потом явно отображаются на сайте, то еще обрабатывают с помощью `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: <textarea cols="30" rows="10" name="text"></textarea>

На выводе использую htmlspecialchars($text)... этого достаточно?

Comment: @vinnie вполне!

Comment: а как бороться с "длинным словом" без пробела?

Comment: как вариант - стилями ограничить ширину выводимого текста и прописать в css свойство overflow:hidden; - тогда всё, что не умещается по ширине, будет скрываться; либо при сохранении смотрим все слова и если длина слова больше, чем лимит символов (скажем, 100), то делаем слову substr